Docker Vite not found error for VueJs and Laravel on seperate project
I have a seperate project VueJs and Laravel that I intend to Dockerize.  Going inside the VueJS project and issuing npm run dev that calls vite works correctly.
This is the folder structure and I have put (F) to emphasize a folder
backend(F)
    Dockerfile
    laravel-api(F)
frontend(F)
    Dockerfile
    vue-project(F)
docker-compose.yaml

here's my docker-compose.yaml contents
version: "3.8"
services:
  vuejs:
    build: frontend
    tty: true
    restart: always
    container_name: laravel_vue_fe_container
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/vue-project:/var/www
      - /app/node_modules

and here's my vue-project/Dockerfile content
FROM node:16

RUN npm install -g @vue/cli

WORKDIR /var/www

COPY ./vue-project/package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY vue-project .

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]


I have added already  /app/node_modules in volumes in yaml file but I'm not sure if the I need to create a suffix to point to correct folder vue-project
